# make popup when post data on the same page

Tags: php, jquery

I am working with php. I have a from and submitted this form on the same page.My code is like :

```
<form method="post">
   <input type = "text" name="u_name">
   .....
   <input type = "submit" name = "submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<?php
   $u_name = $_POST["u_name"];
   //insert query here
?>
```

Here I have post data into the same page. Now I want to create popup like record is successfully inserted after successfully insert data. So what code should I have to do?

Comment: Did you try Googling how to make a popup? We are not going to write your code for you.

Comment: btw, what is the "from" tag ? oO

Comment: What have you tried from your end? You will only get solution here for where you're stuck. This is not a freelancing website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use javascript alert :-

```
<?php
$u_name = $_POST["u_name"];
//insert query here
echo '<script language="javascript">';
echo 'alert("record is successfully inserted")';
echo '</script>';
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

**First**: you cannt submit your form with the "from" tag , I think you mean "form".

**For your question:**

1) post the data via [jQuery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

2) receive a response from your server (HTTP response return from your PHP)

3) show popup window based on the response (via alert function or some js libs like [SweetAlert](http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/) )

**Talk is cheap , show me the code**

client:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>title</title>    
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="path/to/sweetalert.css"/>
    <script src="path/to/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="path/to/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" id="myform">
       <input type = "text" name="u_name">
       <input type = "submit" name = "submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</body>
<script>
    $(function(){

        $('#myform').submit(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var u_name = $('input[name="u_name"]').val();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'http://your.url',
                data: {
                    u_name:u_name
                },
                dataType: "JSON",
                success: function(res) {
                    //alert(res.msg);
                    sweetAlert("popup window", res.msg, "info");
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
</html>
```

server:

```
<?php
define('SUCCESS_CODE', 1);
define('SUCCESS_MSG', 'Success!');

$name = isset($_POST['u_name']) ? $_POST['u_name'] : '';
$res = array(
    'code' => SUCCESS_CODE,
    'msg'  => SUCCESS_MSG,
    'data' => $name
 );

echo json_encode($res);
exit();
?>
```

Comment: I suggest you to improve your example by reading the [Minimal, Complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @IlGala thanks for your reminder :)